# Vector consisting of Pointers of Class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, sdl-2

let's say I have a vector consisting of pointers of the class Enemy:

```
vector<Enemy*> enemyVect;
```

This vector then gets filled with Enemy pointers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbOfEnemys; i++) {  //add all enemies to vector with random EnemeyType
        int random = rand() % enemyTypesVect.size();
        Enemy* e1 = enemyTypesVect[random];
        enemyVect.push_back(e1);    
    }
```

After this all the Enemies gets assigned a random X-Y coordinate:

```
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < enemyVect.size(); i1++) { //spread enemys out on X-axis
        int randomx = rand() % 720;
        newRect = enemyVect[i1]->getRect();
        newRect.x = randomx;
        enemyVect[i1]->setRect(newRect);
    }

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < enemyVect.size(); i2++) { //spread enemys out on Y-axis
        int random = rand() % 1000;
        newRect = enemyVect[i2]->getRect();
        //newRect.y = random;
        newRect.y = random - 1000;
        enemyVect[i2]->setRect(newRect);
    }
```

At this stage all the Enemies have their unique position. While the program is running I'm looping through this vector and I'm trying to make them move in Y-axis:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemyVect.size(); i++) {

            newRect = enemyVect[i]->getRect();
            newRect.y += enemyVect[i]->getSpeed();
            enemyVect[i]->setRect(newRect);
            enemyVect[i]->draw();
}
```

This is where the problem occurs, since all Enemies gets set to the exact same position. So it occurs as if there is only one Enemy, but in reality there are 30 of them, just stacked on top of eachother. I'm not too familiar with C++, but i'm guessing it has to do with all the pointers looking at the same copy that is being set? Worth noting is that enemyTypesVect only consists of 1 type of enemy at the moment, if I add one more then 2 enemies are being drawn. What do I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance and let me know if I should include more code :)

Function for draw():

```
void Enemy::draw() {
    SDL_RenderCopy(sys.getRen(), getTexture(), NULL, &getRect());
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Think about how many objects you created of each enemy type.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but you should rather use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>> enemyVect;` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Enemy>>` instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part:

```
int random = rand() % enemyTypesVect.size();
Enemy* e1 = enemyTypesVect[random];
enemyVect.push_back(e1);
```

You have an array of enemy types, which in your case is only 1 object. You save a pointer to that object (`e1`), and then you add it to your vector.

The problem is that `e1` points to the same copy every time. The function that sets the x/y coordinates actually sets it for the same object in every iteration.

You could verify this by printing the pointer assigned to `e1`:

```
printf("e1 is %p\n", e1);
```

You'll see that it has the same value for every enemy.

Comment: Yes, I now understand that. So how do I add enemies to enemyVect without them being pointers to the same copy?

Comment: You should use either a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or a [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) design pattern.
The enemy types vector could be replaced by a `factory` object that will instantiate new object for you instead of returning an existing one.